# Is there a way to see a list of Templates in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

I am trying to manage my templates, but I can't seem to find a listing of them in team city.

I can go into each project, find the template and the click on it, but that only helps if I know which projects use which templates.

**Is there a way in TeamCity to see all the templates?**